# TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined

Tags: jquery, typeerror

In my chat script an error occurs on the following lines:

```
$("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent")
.scrollTop($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);
setTimeout('$("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent")
.scrollTop($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);', 100);
```

Comment: `$(...)[0]` is undefined: The error message is quite clear as to what the problem is.. What are the contents of `$("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent")`?

Comment: What is the full uncut error? In what context is this code placed? Just this code doesn't tell us very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent")
    .scrollTop($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxcontent")[0].scrollHeight);
}, 100);
```

Comment: <?php for($i=0;$i<count($FriendsList);$i++){ ?>

    <div class="postimgsec">
<img onclick="javascript:chatWith('<?php $n= explode(" ",$FriendsList[$i]->name);echo $n[0]; ?>')" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?><?php echo $FriendsList[$i]->photo; ?>" width="46" height="42" alt="">
<h5><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/friendaccount/friend_profile/<?php echo $FriendsList[$i]->user_id; ?>" title="<?php echo ucwords($FriendsList[$i]->name); ?>"><?php echo substr(ucwords($FriendsList[$i]->name),0,6); ?></a></h5>

</div>
 <?php } ?>